# Pycharm : import Boto 3

Tags: python, pycharm, boto, boto3

I followed the steps on this installation guide : 
https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html#guide-quickstart

After I did all the steps I still can't import `boto3` in my `Pycharm` `python` file.
I'm using `python 3.4.3`.

Comment: Can you show us the error you are getting when you try to import boto3?

Comment: are you using correct python interpreter in your pycharm? you might want to refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776857/suddenly-i-cant-import-pygame-when-using-pycharm5/33778616#33778616

Answer (score 16):

In Pycharm

- Press <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>
- On left, `Project <your project here>` > `Project Interpreter`
- On right, click on `+`
- At the top, `search` for `boto3`
- At the bottom, click on `Install Package`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the Boto3 package to PyCharm.

This answer provides a visual reference. [ImportError: No module named 'bottle' - PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069254/importerror-no-module-named-bottle-pycharm)

Answer (score -2):

Try following command in the terminal

```
pip install boto3
```